# NullPointerException when using CXF SSE by @Context SseEventSink

Tags: nullpointerexception, jax-rs, cxf, tomcat8, server-sent-events

I am trying to use JAX-RS SSE(Server-sent event) feature in **Tomcat 8.0.45** and **Apache CXF 3.2.8**, but always get a `NullPointerException` when send the GET request from browser via javascript `new EventSource(url)`. Following is the code:

```
@Path("/sse")
public class SSEService {
    @GET
    @Path("/test")
    @Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    public void test(@Context Sse sse, @Context SseEventSink eventSink) {
        try (SseEventSink sink = eventSink) {
            sink.send(sse.newEvent("Hello world"));
        }
    }
}
```

The exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerExecption
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.AsyncResponseImpl.initContinuation(AsyncResponseImpl.java:306)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.AsyncResponseImpl.<init>(AsyncResponseImpl.java:68)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.sse.SseEventSinkContextProvider.createContext(SseEventSinkContextProvider.java:47)
    ......
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does it also occur with the latest 3.3.0 release? If so please create a bug report here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/CXF/

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem. I am stuck at same error.